# dplyr: calculate group weights

Tags: r, dplyr

Quick question, how to calculate group weights using `dplyr`?

For example, given data:

```
D = data.frame(cat=rep(LETTERS[1:2], each=2), val=1:4)

#   cat val
# 1   A   1
# 2   A   2
# 3   B   3
# 4   B   4
```

The desired result should be:

```
#   cat weight
# 1   A    0.3     # (1+2)/10
# 2   B    0.7     # (3+4)/10
```

Anything more succinct than the following?

```
D %>% 
  mutate(total=sum(val)) %>% 
  group_by(cat) %>% 
  summarise(weight=sum(val/total))
```

Comment: Try `D%>%group_by(cat) %>% summarise(weight=sum(val)/sum(D[,2]))` but not elegant as your code

Comment: Skip "dplyr" and use base? `prop.table(xtabs(val ~ cat, D))`

Comment: Whooop, what just happened there, @AnandaMahto! Interesting

Comment: @DanielKrizian, if you're into "data.table", you can also try: `as.data.table(D)[, list(val = sum(val)/sum(D$val)), by = cat]`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd write it as

```
D <- data.frame(
  cat = rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = 2), 
  val = 1:4
)

D %>% 
  group_by(cat) %>%
  summarise(val = sum(val)) %>%
  mutate(weight =  val / sum(val))
```

Which you can simplify a little using `count()` (only in dplyr >= 0.3) and `prop.table()`:

```
D %>% 
  count(cat, wt = val) %>%
  mutate(weight = prop.table(n))
```